# How to correctly define multiple sets of values as config values in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I have a snakefile that is looping through a set of isolates to run 2 python scripts. I want to set a set of values as the script flags but I do not know how to do it without a bash script.

```
import os
grouphome = os.environ['GROUPHOME']
ISOLATES = [i for i in open(grouphome+'/isolates.txt').read().split('\n') if len(i) > 0]
window_size=config["window_size"]
slide_size=config["slide_size"]
mean_filter_size =config["mean_filter_size"]
rule all:
    input:
        expand(grouphome+"/preprocessed_coverage_{window_size}_{slide_size}_{mean_filter_size}/{isolate}.csv", isolate=ISOLATES,window_size=config["window_size"],slide_size=config["slide_size"],mean_filter_size=config["mean_filter_size"]),
        expand(grouphome+"/preprocessed_coverage_{window_size}_{slide_size}_{mean_filter_size}/ptr/{isolate}/ptr.csv", isolate=ISOLATES,window_size=config["window_size"],slide_size=config["slide_size"],mean_filter_size=config["mean_filter_size"]),
        expand(grouphome+"/preprocessed_coverage_{window_size}_{slide_size}_{mean_filter_size}/ptr/{isolate}/residuals_fitted_values.csv",isolate=ISOLATES,window_size=config["window_size"],slide_size=config["slide_size"],mean_filter_size=config["mean_filter_size"])
rule coverage_preprocessing:
    input:
        input1= grouphome+"/data/{isolate}.fasta",
        input2= grouphome+"/max_coverage/{isolate}_maximum_coverage.csv"
    params:
        window_size=config["window_size"],
        slide_size=config["slide_size"],
        mean_filter_size =config["mean_filter_size"]
    output: grouphome+"/preprocessed_coverage_{window_size}_{slide_size}_{mean_filter_size}/{isolate}.csv"
    shell:
        """./preprocess_coverage.py -i {input.input2} -g {input.input1} -sw {params.slide_size} -ws {params.window_size} -m mean -bm mean -bs {params.mean_filter_size} -o {output}"""
rule calc_bptr:
    params:
        window_size=config["window_size"],
        slide_size=config["slide_size"],
        mean_filter_size =config["mean_filter_size"]
    input:
        input1= grouphome+"/data/{isolate}.fasta",
        input2= grouphome+"/preprocessed_coverage_{window_size}_{slide_size}_{mean_filter_size}/{isolate}.csv"
    output:
        output1= grouphome+"/preprocessed_coverage_{window_size}_{slide_size}_{mean_filter_size}/ptr/{isolate}/ptr.csv",
        output2= grouphome+"/preprocessed_coverage_{window_size}_{slide_size}_{mean_filter_size}/ptr/{isolate}/residuals_fitted_values.csv",
    shell:
        """./calculate_bptr.py -i {input.input2} -b mean -s {params.mean_filter_size} -g {input.input1} -f {output.output2} -o {output.output1}"""
```

I am using the following command to run it
`snakemake --config window_size=1000000 slide_size=10000 mean_filter_size=99 --cores=9`

How do I set multiple sets of values for --config?
e.g., 1000000,10000,99
1000000,100,66 or etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple layers of the problem.

First, I would prefer passing configfile to snakemake call, e.g.: `snakemake --config config.yaml` with the `config.yaml` containing values for parameters. There, you can specify a list of values for the parameter, such as:

```
window_size:
  - 1000
  - 2000

slide_size:
  - 5
  - 10
```

The second problem is how to run a rule with a list of parameter values.
I would suggest specifying outputs for all parameter values in the `all`, with the downstream rules taking parameter values from wildcards.

```
# this rule requests all combinations of these two parameters, that you passed as a list from the config.
rule all:
    input:
        expand(
            "results/{window_size}_{slide_size}.csv",
            window_size=config["window_size"],
            slide_size=config["slide_size"]
        ),

# this rule parses from the output parameter values, this is accessed using wildcards object
rule preprocess_coverage:
    input:
        ...,
    output: 
        "results/{window_size}_{slide_size}.csv"
    shell:
        "... -sw {wildcards.slide_size} -ws {wildcards.window_size} -o {output}"
```

Using the example `config.yaml` from above, the first rule - `all` rule - requests the following files: `results/1000_5.csv`, `results/1000_10.csv`, `results/2000_5.csv` and `results/2000_10.csv`. Snakemake recognize that the rule `preprocess_coverage` can produce these files by setting the wildcards values, that are then accessed in the `shell` directive of the rule as parameters for the script.

See more about wildcards [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/master/snakefiles/rules.html#wildcards), and about expand function [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#the-expand-function).

In `expand` function you can provide any combinatorial function to produce the results, i.e. to produce only `results/1000_5.csv` and `results/2000_10.csv` use the `zip` function:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand(
            "results/{window_size}_{slide_size}.csv",
            zip,
            window_size=config["window_size"],
            slide_size=config["slide_size"]
        ),
```

With Snakemake 5.31 and above, there is also another option: parameter space exploration, there is a well-written description in the [Snakemake manual](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/master/snakefiles/rules.html#parameter-space-exploration). ParamSpace simplifies the above approach, but it works the same with less code. I would recommend to try the above first, as it is important to understand the above to understand how ParamSpace works.

Comment: How about if I don't want to have all combinations defined in the config file? I just want 1000 with 5 and 2000 with 10

Comment: Then you can define the appropriate combinatoric function in the `expand` function, check the [link](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#the-expand-function). in your case you want `zip`. I edit the answer to include the example for `zip`.